# Optimize linear equation using inner products and subject to L1 norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have a linear system of the form $A x = b$ where $A$ and $b$ are known, $A$ is "square", and $\lvert b \rvert_1 = \lvert x \rvert_1 = 1$. Unfortunately, I am working in a framework that only gives me access to a dot product, not the individual vector or operator elements. The only way I have found to solve this problem is by optimizing the quantity:

$$ d^2 = \lvert b - A x \rvert_2 = \langle b, b \rangle - 2 \langle b, A x \rangle + \langle A x, A x \rangle $$

subject to the normalization $\lvert x \rvert_1 = 1$. This tends to work, but it becomes computationally challenging to compute the last term because of the double operator. (Forming the vector $A x$ is actually very difficult, so I have to compute the inner product "all at once" to use this toolset: $\langle A x, A x \rangle = x^T A^T A x$.)

Now, if this were an $L^2$ constrained problem, I could use ${d^\prime}^2 = 1 - \langle b, A x \rangle$ as the "overlap" between states $b$ and $A x$, which makes more sense to me coming from a quantum mechanics perspective, yet, because $x$ is only $L^1$ normalized, I would still have to ensure that $b$ and $A x$ are $L^2$ normalized before optimizing this way -- which takes me back to computing $\langle A x, A x \rangle$ at every step, which is, again, too expensive. The operator $A$ *does* guarantee that the $L^1$ norm is preserved, but the $L^2$ norm is, in general, not.

I can't think of another approach to solve this equation using only inner products. Have I missed something obvious? Or is there literature out there about solving this problem? Google has yet to be helpful on this issue, because "$L^1$ optimization" is a common search and does not seem to be related to my question, since $A$ in that problem is apparently sparse. *Please explain any answers at an advanced-undergrad-core-math level, because I am not a mathematician.*

Comment: In principle using products like $\langle e_i, A e_j \rangle$ can be used to reconstruct $A_{i,j}$, similar for $b_i$; after that solve it the usual way.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Thanks for the suggestion. I'm actually working with objects that have been decomposed using tensor train decomposition, so they are typically far too large to actually store reconstructed like that.

Comment: How about using the Krylov method (GMRES) for it? It needs only products that are available to you.

Comment: @MaximUmansky I had thought about that... But doesn't the Krylov method require a lot of inner products and compression steps to keep the ranks under control?

Comment: Well, GMRES is one of leading methods for large sparse matrices; depending on the sparsity structure of your matrix, it could be a good way to deal with it anyway, even if it was fully accessible.

Comment: Leaving aside the computational difficulties, what problem are you trying to solve? Does $Ax = b$ not actually hold exactly, but you want to find $x$ which provides the best fit in some sense, subject to some constraint(s)? So minimize norm(A*x-b) where norm is some norm, perhaps the one norm? And if so, is there also a constraint on x that one norm of x = 1? Once the problem to be solved is clearly defined, what exactly are the computations you can and can not do Are the values of $A$ and $b$ available to provide as inputs to an optimization function?

Comment: Minimizing the one norm of $Ax-b$ subject to one norm of x = 1 is a Llinear Programming problem, for which very efficient solvers exist for solving large sparse problems.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I can go into a little more detail here. I'm trying to do a time evolution problem with implicit timestepping, so $A \approx I - \Delta B$, with $y^\prime = B y$ as my governing equation. Since this is an implicit problem, I need to solve for the next $y$ given the previous $y$, so $b = y^n$ and $x = y^{n+1}$ here. $y$ should be constrained to have 1-norm equal to unity for all $n$. I can essentially take any inner product between any combination of operators and vectors so long as the output is a scalar, but more operators means more computational time.